# How to avoid sikuli creating a png file when using "with Region"

Tags: sikuli

I have the following code in sikulix (version 2015-01-06)

```js
...
t = wait("total_power.png")
area = Region(t.x+t.w, t.y, 80, 31)

with Region(area):
    wait("num_1.png")
    ....
```

I find that "with Region" will create a png file in the same directory of the python file. And the png file is the region that I want.
How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

What is is it that you are trying to do here? 
Is it that you would like to wait until a window appears, and then look inside that window for another picture to appear?

In that case you alreay have defined the region when you found "t". 
"t" is the location of the picture "total_power.png"

For example:

```
# Wait until the window appears. 
p1 = wait("image1.png")
# Find another picture inside the window. 
p2 = p1.wait("image2.png")
```

Edit:

You should have a look here: [Link](http://doc.sikuli.org/region.html) 
I think you could use the .right(), if you leave the () empty you take everything. 
If fill in a a value you take a part of the screen. 
I use .hightlight() when programming to show me what region I am looking at.

You can also use region1.union(region2) to merge 2 region to a new one.

An example:

```
Image1 = ("image1.png")

class Blue():
    def __init__(self):
        # Find an image. 
        LocImage1 = find(Image1)
        # Too show the user the region we selected, we can highlight if for 5 seconds. 
        LocImage1.highlight(5)
        # Grab the region to the right of this image. 
        LocImage1RightSide = LocImage1.right()
        # Highlight the region again. 
        LocImage1RightSide.highlight(5)

# Run class 
Blue()
```

Comment: What I am looking for is in the right side of "total_power.png", not inside. <br> That's why I create another region and use "with Region" syntax.

Comment: I think you need to use .right() 
I edited my post with an example.

Comment: Thank you, Tenzin.
However, my question is to avoid the creation of png file when using "with Region". Not to set the region next to it.
Anyway, region.find() works and don't create png file.